# Examples of Root Fields over $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This exercise originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 31, B1.

> Show that, in any extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ which contains a root $u$ of
>   \begin{align*}
>     a(x) &= x^3 + 2x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]
> \end{align*}
>   it happens that $u + 1$ and $u + 2$ are the remaining two roots of $a(x)$.
>   Use this fact to find the root field of $x^3 + 2x + 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$.
>   List the elements of the root field.

Given $a(u)=0, a(u+1)=(u+1)^3 + 2(u+1) + 1 = (u^3+1)+(2u+2)+1 = a(u) = 0$.

Similarly, $a(u+2)=(u+2)^3 + 2(u+2) + 1 = (u^3+2) + (2u+1) + 1 = a(u) = 0$.

This shows $u,u+1,u+2\in\mathbb{Z}_3(u)\implies\mathbb{Z}_3(u)$ is the root field of
$x^3 + 2x + 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Viewed as a vector space with basis $\{1, u, u^2\}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_3(u)$ has a total of $3^3=27$ elements:
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\begin{array}{r r r} \\
   0,         & 1,          & 2, \\
   u,         & u+1,        & u+2, \\
   2u,        & 2u+1,       & 2u+2, \\
   u^2,       & u^2+1,      & u^2+2, \\
   u^2+u,     & u^2+u+1,    & u^2+u+2, \\
   u^2+2u,    & u^2+2u+1,   & u^2+2u+2, \\
   2u^2,      & 2u^2+1,     & 2u^2+2, \\
   2u^2+u,    & 2u^2+u+1,   & 2u^2+u+2, \\
   2u^2+2u,   & 2u^2+2u+1,  & 2u^2+2u+2 \\
\end{array}$

Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I just noticed that you haven't shown that the polynomial is irreducible. This is very easy to do - just check that it has no roots, and use the fact that a cubic polynomial with no roots is irreducible.

Yep, looks good! Just a small note for extra context:

You've shown that the root field is a field with $27$ elements. In fact, for any prime $p$ and integer $n \geq 1$, there is **exactly** one field of size $p^n$, commonly denoted $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ or $\text{GF}(p^n)$ for "Galois Field", and this is a field extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of degree $n$. You can actually prove this without too much machinery - I'd recommend looking it up if you're interested. Thus, when the question asks you to find "the" root field, I think it would probably be natural to say that the answer is $\mathbb{F}_{3^3}$, since this actually tells us exactly what the field is up to isomorphism. An immediate corollary is that actually the root field is the same for **any** irreducible cubic.

Apologies if you already knew this - just thought I'd throw it out there in case you didn't ^_^

Comment: Don't know any of this as I am still at Chapter 31, but I am on my way in that direction.  Thanks for the preview.

Comment: You’re welcome! Enjoy.